# Styled background used in layout of transparent PopupWindow not working

Tags: android, android-layout

So I have this class that extends `PopupWindow`. I set the class's background to `@android:color/transparent` and use the following layout for it's contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tips_root"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    style="?Tips_Background" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textInfo"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/register_termsandconditions" 
        style="?TextAppearance_Footer" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnClose"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="0dip"
        android:layout_gravity="top|right"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_dialog_normal" 
        style="@style/App_ImageButtonStyle" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The idea is to get a popup like so:

[image: My Custom Tips Window]

The style that I use to achieve this effect is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:visible="false">

    <gradient 
        android:startColor="@color/trademark_dark"
        android:endColor="@color/trademark_darkest"
        android:angle="90" />

    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#AAAAAA" />
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />

    <padding 
        android:left="8dp" 
        android:top="8dp"
        android:right="8dp" 
        android:bottom="8dp" />

</shape>
```

Things are working as expected, except in my startup activity where the window appears completely transparent as if the background had no effect at all.

[image: My Transparent Tips Window]

I have the theme containing this style applied to the whole application using:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:theme="@style/NI_AppTheme.Trademark"
    android:name="NApplication">
    <activity android:name="LoginActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  ....
```

`LoginActivity` is the only activity in which I'm facing this problem. What could I be missing?

**UPDATE:**

The solution outlined by @imran khan works. However, I need to reference this value through a theme attribute rather than a direct hardcoded reference as the background will vary with themes. I tried:

```
<style name="NI_AppTheme.Trademark">
    <item name="Tips_Background">@drawable/application_tips_trademark</item>
</style>
```

And then set the layouts' `android:background="?Tips_Background"`, but it crashes the application with the following stack trace:

```
 06-25 21:09:36.518: E/AndroidRuntime(874): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f01002e a=-1}
 06-25 21:09:36.518: E/AndroidRuntime(874):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1897)
 06-25 21:09:36.518: E/AndroidRuntime(874):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
 06-25 21:09:36.518: E/AndroidRuntime(874):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2785)
 06-25 21:09:36.518: E/AndroidRuntime(874):     at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:385)
 06-25 21:09:36.518: E/AndroidRuntime(874):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:174)
 06-25 21:09:36.518: E/AndroidRuntime(874):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:170)
```

Comment: manish try using selector instead of shape

Comment: use android:background="@drawable/Tips_Background" and put shape xml in res/drawable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activity is the only Context on which the themes defined in your manifest are actually attached.  Any other instance will use the system default theme to inflate your views, leading to a display output you probably didn’t expect.

[Context, What Context?](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/06/context/)

This is why `getApplicationContext()` will not properly set your theme.

Comment: Been a year, but the best explanation i got. Accepting your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Put tips_root background shap xml in **res/drawable**.
Use `android:background` instead of `style="?Tips_Background"` as:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tips_root"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/Tips_Background" >
```

Comment: This works. Thanks!. Could you enlighten me about what might be happening? Also I need this to be variable according to theme. Please see update above for why I need to have this come from a theme attribute rather than directly referencing a drawable.

Answer (score 0):

I ultimately narrowed down the problem to my passing the context returned by `getApplicationContext()` to the `PopupWindow` constructor. If I pass `LoginActivity.this` as the context, things work as expected and I'm able to change backgrounds according to theme selected in the parent activity.

Still beats me why `getApplicationContext()` would not have the theme I set on it. Food for thought.