# Cannot use standard android color attribute in custom color selector

Tags: android, android-theme

So, android defines the following in `themes.xml`:

```
<style name="Theme">
    ...
    <item name="colorPressedHighlight">@color/legacy_pressed_highlight</item>
</style>
```

and:

```
<style name="Theme.Holo">
    ...
    <item name="colorPressedHighlight">@color/holo_blue_light</item>
</style>
```

I want to use this `colorPressedHighlight` as the background color for my custom `Button` when it is pressed. So I defined the following in `res/color/app_button_background.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="?android:colorPressedHighlight"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

Finally, I define my custom `ImageButton` style:

```
<style name="App_ImageButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.ImageButton">
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/app_button_background</item>
</style>
```

I crash on app launch with the following call stack:

```
06-27 20:24:41.954: E/AndroidRuntime(532): Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #6: <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable
06-27 20:24:41.954: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:178)
06-27 20:24:41.954: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:867)
06-27 20:24:41.954: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:804)
06-27 20:24:41.954: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1920)
```

I know that directly accessing `@color/legacy_pressed_highlight` or `@color/holo_blue_light` instead of accessing them through the `colorPressedHighlight` fixes the crash but it does not solve the problem. Themes can vary, hence I need to access it through the `colorPressedHighlight` attribute.

PS: I had a similar [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11189401/styled-background-used-in-layout-of-transparent-popupwindow-not-working) to which I haven't found an answer yet. Can someone please help!

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you also need to declare the attribute reference in file res/values/attrs.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <attr name="colorPressedHighlight" format="reference" />
</resources>
```

And refer to it as `?colorPressedHighlight` instead as `?android:colorPressedHighlight`.